# How to display real time serial port data using OpenGL C/C++

Tags: opengl, serial-port, video-streaming

I am writing a C program that reads serial data from COM3 (these data are actually pixel intensities of a stream of video frames); once one frame is received completely, the program re-assembles the frame and displays it using OpenGL; next frame comes, display the next frame. (so in the end it looks like a video)

To me, it seems that I need one thread to receive data and another thread to display? Since the program must not stop receiving data.

I have finished data receiving and frame re-assembling part but I have no idea how the display part work.
Can anybody give me any clue how to do this?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't have to do this on different threads. Consider this pseudocode:

```
while (true) {
    if (data_present())
        read_data();

    display();
}
```

From what I understood from your question, you want to present raster data on the screen. In this case, instance the data in contiguous memory buffer, create a texture of it and render it on a quad or two triangles covering the whole screen.

Comment: It actually depends on the UART FIFO size. If processing the data into a frame takes longer than FIFO size / bitrate you'll loose data and/or synchronization. Using a secondary thread for data read-processing into a `glMapBuffer`-ed PBO makes most sense to me.

Comment: Okey, buffering is another issue, but I still believe it can be solved on one thread.

Comment: It really depends on the data rate. In my professional job for example I'm dealing with data rates of over 2.5GiByte/s that are to be visualized in realtime (results presented 4 weeks ago at the BiOS 2013 conference). This couldn't be done without fine tuned multithreading.

Comment: Okey... I don't actually feel competent to proceed into this discussion further, because my ignorance will start to show up :). And now that I think about it, it's a very interesting topic.